# How to convert date to different format?

Tags: coldfusion

I have

```
<cfset DateToday = "#now()#" />
<cfdump var = "#DateToday#" />
```

Which gives me:

```
{ts '2014-04-28 15:37:52'}
```

How can I change it to give me to 'April 28,2014'?
I would think I would have to use convert to char?

Comment: With this type of question, always take a look at the [functions by category](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec1a60c-7ffc.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6986) of the docs first. In this case, "Date and Time functions" => `DateFormat()`.

Comment: You don't need " or # in your cfset

Comment: You might not even need the cfset.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
#DateTimeFormat(DateToday, "mmmm d, yyyy")#
```